# Как сгруппировать данные, чтобы они шли друг за другом?

Tags: база-данных, администрирование, ms-access

[image: Есть таблицы с данными]

Я хочу вывести number1, title, theme и idea друг за другом, а после сделать группировку по subjectname. Примерно так:

number1 **1**
title titlename
theme themename
idea ideaname

number1 **2**
title titlename
theme themename
idea ideaname

number1 **3**
title titlename
theme themename
idea ideaname

---

Subjectname **subject1**

Subjectname **subject2**

Subjectname **subject3**

Subjectname **subject4**

Subjectname **subject5**

Comment: Две совершенно несвязанные выборки получаются... так что два независимых суб-отчёта в основном отчёте, каждый со своим источником данных.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! Если впишете его как ответ, отмечу как решение)